# Making a battery pack out of 8 cells in 4S2P configuration

Tags: power, power-electronics

I want to make a battery pack of 4S2P using 8cells. Is it better to first make 2 sets of 4 cells each (4 cells joined in series to each other) and then join these 2 sets in parallel or first making 4 sets of 2 cells each (2 cells joined in parallel with each other) and then join the 4 sets in series? And Why?

Comment: it depends on the batteries chemistries with a highly variable voltage that tracks charge state like lithium polymer work well connected in parallel,

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to wire 2 series' of 4 batteries parallel to each other, rather than series wiring 4 parallel pairs together.

This is because you should add shunt/balancing resistors to each battery (or series of batteries) to ensure that every parallel unit "does its share," rather than one battery/series with slightly lower internal resistance burning itself out by performing (sometimes as high as) 90% of the work.

To balance parallel power supplies like this, figure out your anticipated max. amperage load, then size a resistor to cause ~10% voltage drop at that load; then attach a resistor of that value to each lower supply. This will cause a total voltage drop of ~5% in the shunt resistors (so 95% efficiency remaining) at max. load, and less loss at any lower load.

Like this:
[image: Shunted Batteries]

Comment: Your answer is correct for LEDs .Not so sure about batteries.

Comment: @Autistic I'm not sure if the resistor sizing is correct for LEDs (I didn't check), but the diagram is a simplified version of what I had to install when repairing an improperly built 16KW small Solar (PV) power station with ~250KWH total battery capacity (i.e. something you do _**NOT**_ want to have overload while you're standing near it. ;)

Comment: Does cell characteristics play any role in this? If yes, what?

Comment: @KanishkaPanda Yes. As you approach the max. amperage output the batteries can support, the variation between the internal resistances of the batteries becomes significant & (for installations such as the solar power station reserve bay) you should periodically test the total internal resistance of each batt. series, then compensate the difference by modifying the values of the shunt resistors so that (internal resistance series 1)+shunt1 = (internal resistance series 2)+shunt 2. HOWEVER for using semi-disposable batteries in a consumer device this would usually be unnecessary (& impossible).